# Are extension classes in a mulitithreading WCF environment thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, wcf, thread-safety, msmq

I have different products running asynchronously when suddenly I get scenarios that another product's details ended up in another product.

I have it stored in XML when I transfer it to another service.

Running at:

```
var transactionScopeOptions = new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, Timeout = Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0) };
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionScopeOptions))
{
    using (var dataContext = new FooContext())
    {
        /* code goes here, single instance of dataContext per thread */
    }
}
```

With the extension class (where it goes wrong) of:

```
public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static int GetID(this FooClass foo)
    {
        var result = foo != null ? foo.ID : 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

How do I make it thread safe if this is not thread safe?

**EDIT:**

It could also be that a memory leak is happening, not sure though.
Using WCF `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` and `InstanceContextMode.Single`

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are no less thread-safe than any other methods.  They are simply syntactic sugar on top of normal static methods.  In fact, instead of doing `foo.GetID()`, you can call the same method as `FooExtensions.GetID(foo)` and it will do the same exact thing.  This is what the compiler is really doing for you under the hood.

Based on the example you gave, your extension method is thread-safe.  Your problem is more likely due to using `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted`.  `ReadUncommitted` can result in dirty reads, non-repeatable reads, the same data being read twice, and phantom reads.  See [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tamarick_hill/archive/2013/05/06/pros-cons-of-using-read-uncommitted-and-nolock.aspx) for details.  I would recommend increasing your isolation level and seeing if that makes your problems go away.